# Loading Json Data into an AmChart

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I am new to AmCharts and attempting to load json data from a variable into a sparkline type chart, the chart is loading however the values / line is not, here is what I am doing, how can I correct this? Thank you.

```
data = {2018-04-28 17:03:04: "9.2090000000", 2018-04-28 18:03:15: "9.1870000000", 2018-04-28 19:06:43: "9.1870000000", 2018-04-28 20:07:41: "9.1880000000", 2018-04-28 21:08:16: "9.1810000000", …}

   AmCharts.makeChart( id, {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [data],
  "categoryField": data.key,
  "autoMargins": false,
  "marginLeft": 0,
  "marginRight": 5,
  "marginTop": 0,
  "marginBottom": 0,
  "graphs": [ {
    "valueField": data.value,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "lineColor": "#ffbf63",
    "negativeLineColor": "#289eaf"
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "guides": [ {
      "value": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 0.1
    } ]
  } ],
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "startOnAxis": true
  }
} );
```

Comment: This is not valid Object syntax. Your keys have to either be Strings or Numbers

Comment: You object syntax to data is invalid and commas are missing after few properties. Have a check on it.

Comment: Also i checked AmCharts API, Seems like you must pass array of objects having each data points and values to dataProvider instead of single object having all data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, AmCharts expects an array of objects. What you have is a single object with (invalid looking) key-value entries.

You want your valid JSON response to look something like this:

```
[{
  "date": "2018-04-28 17:03:04",
  "value": 9.2090000000,
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 18:03:15",
  "value": 9.1870000000
},
 // etc
]
```

Your [`valueField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueField) and [`categoryField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#categoryField) properties need to be set to strings that correspond to these keys in your data, e.g.

```
graphs: [{
  // ...
  valueField: "value"
}],
categoryField: "date"
```

Since you're using date-based data, you might also want to consider setting [`parseDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) to true and a [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) so that it can parse the dates and manage periods correctly. You'd also need to set a [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) to correspond to the smallest possible interval between your points (`"hh"` for hours or `"mm"` for minutes should suffice in this case):

```
categoryAxis: {
  parseDates: true,
  minPeriod: "mm",
  // ...
},
dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
```

Here's a working demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "date": "2018-04-28 17:03:04",
  "value": "9.2090000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 18:03:15",
  "value": "9.1870000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 19:06:43",
  "value": "9.1870000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 20:07:41",
  "value": "9.1880000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 21:08:16",
  "value": "9.1810000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 22:08:29",
  "value": "9.1840000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-28 23:08:30",
  "value": "9.1870000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 00:10:12",
  "value": "9.2380000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 01:10:39",
  "value": "9.3180000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 02:10:57",
  "value": "9.5170000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 03:11:56",
  "value": "9.4510000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 04:13:41",
  "value": "9.4490000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 05:13:43",
  "value": "9.4520000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 06:15:47",
  "value": "9.3810000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 07:16:46",
  "value": "9.4440000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 08:17:47",
  "value": "9.4100000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 09:18:31",
  "value": "9.2130000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 10:19:47",
  "value": "9.2680000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 11:21:00",
  "value": "9.2810000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 12:22:08",
  "value": "9.3430000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 13:23:47",
  "value": "9.3270000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 14:23:51",
  "value": "9.3680000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 15:24:13",
  "value": "9.3770000000"
}, {
  "date": "2018-04-29 16:25:53",
  "value": "9.4210000000"
}];

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": data,
  "categoryField": "date",
  "autoMargins": false,
  "marginLeft": 0,
  "marginRight": 5,
  "marginTop": 0,
  "marginBottom": 0,
  "graphs": [{
    "valueField": "value",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "lineColor": "#ffbf63",
    "negativeLineColor": "#289eaf"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "guides": [{
      "value": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 0.1
    }]
  }],
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "mm",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "startOnAxis": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**chart.data accepts only array of objects, move json to array of object**

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    for (i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {  
        chart.data.push({ "EmployeeName": data[i].EmployeeName, "Salary": data[i].Salary});
    }

    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "EmployeeName";
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function (dy, target) {
        if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
            return dy + 25;
        }
        return dy;
    });

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    // Create series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "Salary";
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "EmployeeName";
    //series.name = "Visits";
    series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

    var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
    columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
    columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
```